# Is there a Firefox 3 addon similar to View Source Chart?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-addon, view-source-chart

Before I upgraded to Firefox 3 I used to constantly use the [View Source Chart Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/655) which shows the source HTML in a very organized, graphical form. Unfortunately, this addon is only for Firefox 2 and the beta version for Firefox 3 now costs $10 on the author's site.

Anyone know of a similar addon that works for Firefox 3?

(of course, I might indeed pay $10 for this, but first want to ask around if there isn't anything better and free, as the version for Firefox 2 had its limitations and I don't really want to pay $10 for something in beta that I can't test out before paying for it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) not sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/6543) It overrides addons compatibility check. Using this tool I managed to bring all of my fav extensions from FF2 to FF3

Answer (score 1):

[View formatted source](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/697) is kinda similar. It uses tree controls rather than pretty colour blocks, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try Chris Pederick's Web Developer Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try Firefug. It sounds like it does a similar thing, plus more :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem...
you can use the free version (2.5.0503)...it's compatible with firefox3 and it's work.
on the web site it's write that it's not with full functionality but i don't know whitch functionality there aren't.